# search for text in excel file c#

Tags: c#

I'm writing a windows application with c# and in one form I want to use a n excel file in this way.

In the form when the user types the Employee ID in a text box I wanna search the excel file and based on the ID show other information for the employee in some other text boxes(name text box, last name text box ,status textbox ,and food count text box)

please tell me how can I retrieve the info from it .

```
public List <string>[] RetrieveColumnGeneral(Excel.Worksheet sheet,string FindWhat)
    {
        int columnCount = sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
        List<string>[] columnValue = new List<string>[columnCount];
        Excel.Range rngResult = null;
        Excel.Range rng = null;

        int index = 0;
        int rowCount = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        Excel.Range FindRange = null;
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;columnIndex++ )
        {
            FindRange = sheet.UsedRange.Columns[columnIndex] as Excel.Range;
            FindRange.Select();
            rngResult = FindRange.Find(What: FindWhat, LookIn: Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
                LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, SearchOrder: Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows);
            if (rngResult != null)
            {
                columnValue[index] = new List<string>();

                for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;rowIndex++ )
                {
                    rng = sheet.UsedRange[rowIndex, columnIndex] as Excel.Range;
                    if (rng.Value != null)
                    {
                        columnValue[index].Add(rng.Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
                index++;
            }
        }    
        Array.Resize ( ref columnValue , index);
        return columnValue;
    }
```

thanks I found this code . Will you tell me whether this will solve my problem ?(also by some modifications.)

Comment: Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e4x1k99a.aspx

Comment: Use one of microsoft office/excel libraries to get access and functionality for excel files. Go add link and use tab "COM".
Else ethree give a good tip ;)

Comment: I would use http://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: would you please check my question again. I included some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
You have to passed Sheet object, but in below code SQL statement fire and get all records in DataSet object.   

string sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + selectedWorksheetName + "]";
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, excelObject.Connection);
adapter.Fill(activityDataSet, "Results");

if (activityDataSet.Tables[0] != null)
{
     //here you will check which data get based on your columns
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks but the thing is I don't wanna work with database for this purpose . I mean using the excel as a file is satisfactory.

Comment: how ? you are using sql command OleDb connection!so I assume database is involved

Comment: No its only fetching data from Excel.Worksheet

Comment: its used because of application have to connect with excel sheets. Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this.

```
var ds = new DataSet();
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + newSheetName + "]", ConnectionString);
adapter.Fill(ds, newSheetName);
```

Then use the above dataset to filter the rows.

```
DataRow dataRow = (from DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows where dr["Id"] == textbox.Text select dr).FirstOrDefault();

if(dataRow != null)
{
    // Fill values from this dataRow
}
```

**EDIT**

```
// If excelsheet ends with .xls
string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\ExcelData\QB Accounts.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";

// If excelsheet ends with .xlsx
string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\ExcelData\CSENG01.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
```

Comment: OK. One question. What does FirstOrDefault() function do?

Comment: if you remove the `FirstOrDefault()` then you will get a IEnumerable from the given LINQ query. It is always expected that id is unique. So when when you call `FirstOrDefault()` then you will get a single row with that ID. If ID is missing then you will get a null datarow. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: would there be any problem if I use both OleDb connection and sql server connection in a single application?>

Comment: Yes, You have to used both in single application.

Comment: You must understand one thing. `OleDb` is just an API from Microsoft. It is used to access data from a source. The source may be database, excelsheet, XML or any other file. It exposes functions for a COM object. `OleDb` is not propriety to Database.

Comment: Hi AGAIN. about the the above code.Is "Id" the name of my column in the sheet? cause when I run it says "Column 'Id' does not belong to table Table." . 
Note :my first cell 'A1' is Id .

Comment: The moment you use `adapter.Fill(ds, newSheetName);` then you are no longer dealing with excel sheet anymore and all you have is a dataset with tables which has all data of excel sheet. Debug the code, look for the table which is having your excel sheet data, see the column name in the table and use that in place of `Id`